# Safe unpack empty tuple array

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, iterable-unpacking

The line `import re; print(re.findall("(.*) (.*)", "john smith"))` outputs `[("john", "smith")]`, which can be unpacked like `[(first_name, last_name)] = re.findall(...)`. However, in the event of a non-match (`findall` returning `[]`) this unpacking throws `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)`.

What is the correct way to *safely* unpack this array of tuples, which would work in both match (`[("john", "smith")]`) and non-match (`[]`) scenarios?

Comment: `if result:  # unpacking code`

Comment: `findall` is a weird choice when you only expect (and can only handle) one match.

Comment: @user2357112 I went with it as it's iterable, whereas `search` is not

Comment: @Frayt: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, that makes more sense. I would hope to be able to do something like `first,last = re.search(r"(.*) (.*)", "john smith").groups(default=[None, None])` (which in a non-match scenario errors due to `search` returning `None`)

Comment: `[(first_name, last_name)] = [] or [(None, None)]` ?

Comment: ... how about a `try: except`?

Answer (score 1):

The generic answer is to look before you leap:

```
if result:
    [(first_name, last_name)] = result
```

or to ask for forgiveness:

```
try:
    [(first_name, last_name)] = result
except ValueError:
    pass
```

but you are actually overcomplicating things by using `re.findall()` to find a single result. Use [`re.seach()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and extract your [matched groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups):

```
match = re.search("(.*) (.*)", value)
if match:
    firstname, lastname = match.groups()
```

or

```
try:
    firstname, lastname = re.search("(.*) (.*)", value).groups()
except AttributeError:
    # An attribute error is raised when `re.search()` returned None
    pass
```

Comment: any way to use `re.search` as a one liner, perhaps using the `or` operator as in @bihsing's answer?

Comment: @Frayt: yes, but then you are code golfing, not writing production-level Python code.

Comment: @Frayt: and it'd would require that you create a dummy class with `group()` method that returns `(None, None)` to make the tuple assignment work to be able to do `(re.search("(.*) (.*)", value) or dummy_object).groups()`. That really, really hurts maintainability of your code base.

Comment: I agree that a dummy object is a bad idea for the sake of a one-liner, if None propogation was a thing I could do `first, last = re.search(...)?.groups() or (None, None)`, and I wouldn't consider that 'code golfing'

Comment: @Frayt: right, but `None` in Python is just another object (even though it is a singleton) and not a NULL (which is the absence of an object), so `None`-propagation is not really going to happen in Python.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one; you have to explicitly check the return value to see if there is, in fact, anything to unpack.

```
x = re.findall(...)
if x:
    [(first_name, last_name)] = x
```

In Python 3.8, you'll be able to compact this slightly:

```
if x := re.findall(...):
    [(first_name, last_name)] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `re.findall` returns an empty list in the event of a non-match, you can use the `or` operator to assign default values to `first_name` and `last_name` instead:

```
[(first_name, last_name)] = re.findall("(.*) (.*)", "johnsmith") or [(None, None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible, so don't do it, but you could use

```
first, last = getattr(re.search(r"(.*) (.*)", "john smith"), 'groups', lambda: (None, None))()
```

to do what you want as a one-liner without using `findall` (which could return multiple hits, and so still fail, or ignore spaces depending on whether you limit the `.` to `\S`).

Given your pattern current matches literally anything with a single space in it (capturing everything before the final space, and everything after it), avoid `findall` doesn't gain you much, but if you want to actually exclude stuff with more than one space, or things that match only partially, you could switch the `.` to `\S`, and possibly `search` to `fullmatch`:

```
first, last = getattr(re.fullmatch(r"(\S*) (\S*)", "john smith"), 'groups', lambda: (None, None))()
```

Either way, it abuses the fact that a non-match returns `None`, which has no `groups` method, so `getattr` can return a bound `groups` method on a match, or a `lambda` that returns the defaults otherwise. Regardless, you immediately call it, and get the result of `groups` or the `lambda` as appropriate.

Again, don't do this. It's legal, it's just ugly (and likely slower than any reasonable method).