# How to de-tuple *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a piece of code that queries a database from sqlite and passes each row through a function and then into a class both through *args. The problem is it adds a ,) to the end of it every time it passes through *args. I can get the 0th index every time after I pass it through to get rid of it but I don't always have something passing through *args in which case it comes up with an index out of range error. I figure there's a simpler way to go about this that I just don't know about. Any suggestions?

Not the exact code below but you get the idea of my problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        btn1 = ttk.Button(self, command = self.EditLoadout)
        btn1.pack()
    def EditLoadout(self):
        self.ticketquery = ['cat','hat','bat']

        for x in self.ticketquery:
            self.add_product(x)

    def add_product(self, *args):
        self.newprod = NewProduct(self,args)
        self.newprod.pack(anchor=W)

class NewProduct(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,container,*args):
        print(args)
        Frame.__init__(self)  
my_app = App()
my_app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guess you need to check if the tuple is not empty?

Comment: Dies question is very similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469369/safe-unpack-empty-tuple-array

Comment: @DaniMesejo Ya I can do that but it seems somewhat cumbersome to do every time I pass it through something. I figured there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from your code, your trying to add a new product by passing the variable `args` from `add_product` to the NewProduct `__init__` function. Based on this, what you are doing may not be parsing the args as you think.

One `*` operator is used to pack an uncertain amount of arguments into a Tuple object type. If you print a Tuple, it will look something similar to this: (1, 2, 3, 4)
When you pass a tuple through another function taking in `*args`, you are only passing in one argument.

If you want to pass `args` back as an uncertain amount of variables to another function, you can use `*args` again. An example of this is shown below:

```
def tupleToList(*args):
    print(list(args))

def passThroughFunction(*args):
    print(args) # Prints (1, 2, 3, 4)
    tupleToList(args) # Prints [(1, 2, 3, 4)]
    tupleToList(*args) # Prints [1, 2, 3, 4]

passThroughFunction(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: I figured it'd be something stupidly simple like that. Thanks.